# System.IO.Compression.ZipFile ExtractToDirectory with "overwrite if existing"?

Tags: c#, system.io.compression.zipfile

I want to use `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` with a flag `overwriteIfExisting`, but unfortunately, there is no such parameter.

I saw the github issue on this dated back to 2016 where none of the suggested improvements actually have been made.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/17150

...which is a long discussion, but without a resulting implementation.

Should I use `ExtractToFile` instead? Then I would need to handle recursion myself, right?

Or is there another zip library I should use instead?

Comment: Looks like that github issue was resolved with a new function overload from .NET Core 2.0 onwards https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory?view=net-6.0#system-io-compression-zipfile-extracttodirectory(system-string-system-string-system-boolean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked github issue was resolved with a new function overload for `ExtractToDirectory`, from .NET Core 2.0 onwards.

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory?view=net-6.0#system-io-compression-zipfile-extracttodirectory(system-string-system-string-system-boolean)).

```cs
public static void ExtractToDirectory (
    string sourceArchiveFileName,
    string destinationDirectoryName,
    Encoding? entryNameEncoding,
    bool overwriteFiles);
```